# One computer accessing two completely different networks without VPN

Tags: windows, networking, internet, wired

In our office we have a primary internet connection and a backup connection that is currently unused. I'd like to figure out if it's possible for one or more computers on our network to use the backup connection instead of the main connection and still have access to the other computers on the network (ie File Server).

In other words,  we have two completely separate internet connections (think Cable and DSL). The computers here don't need to be able to access both internet connections but I'd like one or two computers to use the backup connection only AND still have access to the rest of the network. Is this possible without using VPN?

Comment: If you have two network cards you could use static routes to allow both connections. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Are you trying to wire only a single physical LAN? Are the Internet connections connected to separate routers? Give us more details.

Comment: Wouldn't this work? Have the 2 internet connections have different IPs, such as x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2. In the network connections configuration for the computers, most of them will have the default gateway of x.x.x.1 and a few will have x.x.x.2 for the default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these computers are on the same subnet as the others, I would create a vlan for these. Then create a nat rule and a route that makes traffic destined for 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 to route out the other wan interface but limit it to the vlan where those computers reside. You never mentioned your router or edge device or firewall. This would be helpful.